# Flutter - Clear app data when restart the app

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to clear all my app data and the cache when the app's starting or closing. My purpose is to start the app as the first time every time I open it. In my `main.dart` file I'm using this code with the plugin [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider):

```
Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
  final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
    cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  }
}

Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
  final appDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  if (appDir.existsSync()) {
    appDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  }
}

void main() async {
  _deleteCacheDir(); // To clear cache
  _deleteAppDir(); // To clear app's storage
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Initialize plugins
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // Initialize Firebase
  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('circle_ic_appliguide');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int? id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
    }
  });
  runApp(MyApp()); // Run the App
}
```

But it seems do not work... Am I using the good method to release my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the temp folder and delete files in it. Consider a below code snippet:

```
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

Comment: It's the best one for image cache clear. Thanks man !!